# How to prevent user agent stylesheet from overriding my own CSS?

Tags: html, css, browser, doctype

I have to set equal widths to a textbox and a select element.

When I remove the **!DOCTYPE** both the input fields are set to equal lengths,that is 185px each accordingly.

With DOCTYPE the width of the textbox is slightly more than the select element. If I check its width by javascript with **offsetWidth** property it is found to be 189px instead of 185px that I have set in my CSS.

The screenshot of the output:-

[image]

The code snippet:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
 .usrInput{width:185px}
</style>

<body>
<div id="content">
 <form>  
  <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" class="usrInput"/><br/>
  <select name="state" id="state" class="usrInput">
    <option value="">Select State
  </select><br/>  
 </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I think it is the ***user agent stylesheet*** that is somehow overriding my own CSS. I don't know actually **why is it happening and what should I do** to overcome this problem?

Comment: have you tried setting `box-sizing: border-box`?

Comment: @Sirko I have not tried it.

Comment: (FYI: You don’t have to ”guess” in such cases, whether it might be the UA stylesheet or not - browser dev tools help you find that out quite quickly.)

Comment: @CBroe Thanks a ton

Comment: There are some silly people in this world like the one who downvotes this question without any courage to even provide a single hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use

```
.usrInput {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

the dropdown and the input size will match up.

Edit: Usually you can use a css reset such as normalize.css to automatically take care of little quirks like this.